# Sample size for data quality

Tags: random, statistics, sample

For a project I have to perform a data quality check. We have a list of numbers that are calculated by students. As we are not sure that the students performed the formula correctly (to get that number) we want to take a subset of the data to check these values. To get an idea of the percentage correct in the total group of students.

I found that online that 10% of the data is enough for a valuable check, others say N=30 is enough?

My superviser says that we have to check all formula, as just taking a sample will never be good enough, but I believe in a group of 500 students, checking a random number of 50 students will give us a good idea of the total percentage correctly used formulas?

I tried finding a source online to proof my idea, but keep finding sample sizings for hypotheses testing with p-values > which is not the reason for the sample size.

I only find sample size calculations for research projects with p values, but I want to know if this applicable for my case too?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.